# reading a log file and displaying it in jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, thread-sleep

I am trying to read a file that changes dynamically and display its contents in jTextArea.
I am using buffered reader for reading.

I have tried to display the contents on console and it works fine, but doesn't work with jTextArea.

I am doing something like

```
while(true)
{
  line = br.readLine();
  if(line == null)
    Thread.sleep();
  else
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `Thread.sleep()`, you will block the EDT. Instead use a `javax.swing.Timer` if you want to *"animate"* the results. Just read each line each iteration of the timer, until it reaches the end of the file, then stop the timer

```
timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          String line;
           try {
                if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    textArea.append(line + "\n");
                } else {
                   ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                }
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
     }
});
```

Test this program out. I think it works the way you want it to.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ReadFile {

    File file = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    private Timer timer = null;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JTextField jtfFile;
    private String fileName;
    private JButton browse;
    private JFrame frame;

    public ReadFile() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(25, 60);
        frame = new JFrame("Show Log");

        browse = new JButton("Browse");
        browse.addActionListener(new ShowLogListener());

        jtfFile = new JTextField(25);
        jtfFile.addActionListener(new ShowLogListener());

        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String line;
                try {
                    if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        textArea.append(line + "\n");
                    } else {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("File: "));
        panel.add(jtfFile);
        panel.add(browse);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ShowLogListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                fileName = file.getName();
                jtfFile.setText(fileName);
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ReadFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                timer.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new ReadFile();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I do this in my java swing app, it doesn't show the bottom line as it progresses. it just shows the top line.

Comment: meaning, after I append, how do I get the textarea to continue tail to the bottom of the text area so the user sees the latest appended text? it shows the top for me.

Answer (score 2):

2 points:

- Don't call `Thread.sleep()` in the EDT. This blocks the UI and prevents UI updates
- JTextArea has a [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method that allows files to be loaded

Example:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.read(new FileReader("input.txt"), "blah");
```

Comment: I need to stop reading the file when it reaches the end the wait for new write ans log keeps on being written

Answer (score 1):

```
String line;    
String textToDisplay = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    textToDisplay+=line;
textArea.setText(textToDisplay);
```

I used `setText(String)` instead of `append(String)` because it'll replace what is already is in the `JTextArea`... From your question I felt that's what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the text of the text area..try doing so:

```
{
 line = br.readLine();
 if(line == null)
     Thread.sleep();
 else
     textArea.append(line + "\n");
}
```

this will append (put text at end) of the file, meaning that you will not have to worry about text being deleted each time it runs

that should work, hope it helps

Comment: I am doing the same thing... It works in normal cases but with sleep it stops working!!

Comment: well I'm not very familiar with sleep(), but from what I remember, sleep should stop the current thread that is happening. So that is probably why it is not working. Just take out if(line == null) Thread.sleep(); and see if it helps

Comment: if(line == null) lets me wait for new log entries to be added so that it can be read dynamically.